# Firebase auth getAuthState returns null

Tags: typescript, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a nextjs projectt and i'm trying check if a user is logged in and if it is get his id on a server component but I keep on getting null users, tried making the persistence local side and server side, didnt help there's just no way of me getting the auth.currentUser from the firebase/auth.

What is the proper way to set up this environment?

this is my FireBase.tsx:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { Auth, browserLocalPersistence, browserSessionPersistence, debugErrorMap, getAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence, initializeAuth} from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries


// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = {

  apiKey: "AIzaSyA-di4SIrRpAZmEaboJu5IavidbikAf4Zw",

  authDomain: "ids-fidelityprogram-kya.firebaseapp.com",

  projectId: "ids-fidelityprogram-kya",

  storageBucket: "ids-fidelityprogram-kya.appspot.com",

  messagingSenderId: "825561615429",

  appId: "1:825561615429:web:84f50ef8ba2ec8ce39272c",

  measurementId: "G-9XTS9KE82C"

};


// Initialize Firebase

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
const auth = getAuth(app);

auth.setPersistence(browserSessionPersistence);

// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service

export {auth};
```

and this is one example server component where i'm trying to get the currentUser to make a fetch:

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import AuthProvider from "@/hooks/auth";
import { auth } from "../(auth)/(routes)/sign-in/FireBase";
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import authinstance from "firebase/auth";

  export default async function SetupLayout({
    children
  }: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }) {

    

   const user =  auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=> {
      if(!user){
          console.log("user is logged in");
          redirect("/sign-in")
          
      }else{
          console.log("user is not logged in");
          //keeps being not logged in and logging the user returns null
      }
     });
    
     
  //  console.log(user);
    const BASE_URL ='http://localhost:8080/api/v1/'

    //    const store = await fetch(BASE_URL+`${user.uid}/shops`).then((res:any)=> res.data)

     //   if(store){
      //      console.log(store);
     //       store.find((data:any)=>data!==undefined)
     //       redirect(`/${store.id}`)



    return(
        <>

        {children}

        </>
    )
}

function waitForAuthInit() {
  throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
}
```

I tried pretty much everything i've seen on the web and the only thing I managed to make it work was use client side hooks which would kill the SSR purpose of nextjs because it would mean that pretty much every page I render has to check if the user is logged in(right?) i'm pretty new to js and web development.